# How to disable Full Screen button with SwiftUI 2 on macOS

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

As suggested with the title, how should I disable Full Screen button with SwiftUI 2 on macOS?

The only information I could find seems to use features from [`NSWindow`](https://www.marcomatta.com/how-to-disable-the-full-screen-button-with-swiftui/). Is there a native way to do that in SwiftUI 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **macOS 13.0**, you can define `size` for ContentView & set `windowResizability` to `contentSize`.

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView().frame(width: 300, height: 400)
    }.windowResizability(.contentSize)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One thing to note is while using a concrete size(as in your example) works perfectly; as of macOS 13.4 changing that to using a max size modifiers would leave a visible/clickable dummy fullscreen button, despite it won't function.

Answer (score 9):

You can just simply use `.onReceive` modifier to achieve the purpose:

```
struct MacApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .frame(width: 480, height: 272)
            .fixedSize()
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.willUpdateNotification), perform: { _ in
                for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
                    window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isEnabled = false
                }
            })
    }
    .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
}
```

The effect should be as following, the third green button becomes transparent gray:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

YourAppName.Swift

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct YourApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                            window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable]
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check my github project bro https://github.com/sanengineer/ecommerce-admin-macos-swiftui

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.onAppear` modifier to disable full screen button.

```swift
struct MacApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
   WindowGroup {
       ContentView()
           .onAppear {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                       window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isEnabled = false
                   }
               }
           }
   }
   .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32915274)